# Laravel Page is not working on Image upload

Tags: php, image, laravel-5.6

When i'm trying to upload an image (any format), edited via Photoshop, the page is not working, where as if I download any image and then upload the image is working, I don't know whats wrong.

Can any one help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Below is Controller function

```html
public function store(PhotoGalleryRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $gallery = new PhotoGallery($input);
        $filePath = trans('main.photo_gallery.image');

        // File Upload
        if ($input['main_photo']) {
            $fileData = PhotoGallery::uploadFile($input['main_photo'], $filePath);    
            if ($fileData) {
                $fileName               = $fileData['fileOriginalName'];  
                $gallery->main_photo    = $fileName;
                $gallery->thumb_photo   = $fileName;
            }
        } 
        
        $gallery->save();
        return redirect()->route('add-more.showAddMore', STCHelper::encryptUrl($gallery->id));
    }
```

Below is the model function

```html
public static function uploadFile($files,$filePath)
    {
        $return = [];
        if (!empty($files)) {
            $destinationPath = base_path() . $filePath;
            $thumbPath = base_path() . trans('main.photo_gallery.image_thumb');
            if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
               mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, true);
            }
            if (!file_exists($thumbPath)) {
               mkdir($thumbPath, 0777, true);
            }
                $filePath = ($filePath) ? base_path().$filePath : base_path();
                $fileName = STCHelper::setImageName($files->getClientOriginalName());
                $extension = $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileTypes = ['png','jpg','jpeg','JPG'];
                if (in_array(strtolower($extension), $fileTypes)) {
                    $image = Image::make($files->getRealPath());
                    $image->save($destinationPath. $fileName);
                    Image::make($files->getRealPath())->resize(268,268)->save($thumbPath . $fileName);
                    chmod($destinationPath . $fileName, 0777);
                } else {
                    $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $files->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
                    chmod($destinationPath . $fileName, 0777);
                }                
                $return['fileName'] = $fileName;
                $return['filePath'] = trans('main.photo_gallery.image') . $fileName;
                $return['fileType'] = mime_content_type($destinationPath.$fileName); 
                $return['fileExtension'] = $extension;
                $return['fileOriginalName'] = $fileName;
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Below is the screen shot of Error:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some code so that we can see what have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Rob, i hv added my controller and model function

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: Above i have added the screen shot, this is coming when i submit the form

Comment: check your error(apache) log. It's 500. It means there is coding issue

Comment: Yes, i tried Below was the output.                                                                     [21-Jun-2018 07:30:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/svnprojects/StellaMarisArchive/Source/STC/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php on line 1